# Why do we get particular solution when solving non homogeneous differential equation and not general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What I don't understand is that why can't we find the general solution of non homogeneous differential equation from the non homogeneous one itself. Currently we use the homogeneous equation also.

Why isn't it that general solution is not available from the non-homogeneous equation itself?

Comment: Because there would be no way to find it without using the homogeneous equation first. Any particular solution of a **linear** inhomogeneous ODE added to the general solution of its homogeneous part gives the general solution to the original equation. It's how it works

Comment: In principle we can try to directly solve the inhomogeneous ODE, for example by a series method, but it would need to be done from scratch for each equation

Comment: Note that you should mention in the question that this method only works for linear ODEs

Comment: Why do you want this?  If you have two linear ODE's that have the same homogeneous part and different forcing functions, isn't it better to be able to reuse the solution of the homogeneous equation?

Answer (score 4):

The whole point is that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ solve $L(x)=y$, where $L$ is a linear differential operator, then $$0=y-y=L(x_1)-L(x_2)=L(x_1-x_2)$$ so $x_1$ and $x_2$ differ by a homogeneous solution. Note that linearity is crucial here.

(You seem to think the inhomogeneous equation has a *unique* particular solution. But this is not true. When you solve an inhomogeneous equation, you find *a* particular solution of the infinitely many that are available. The other solutions to the equation differ from the one you find by a homogeneous solution, that is, by an element of the kernel of the linear operator.)

Comment: I would add to this that from the practical standpoint, knowing the homogeneous solution, we can use it to find a particular solution for the inhomogeneous equation as well. Which is generally better than trying to guess

Comment: Sure, and agreed (e.g. variation of parameters), but that's not what the OP asked. The general solution of any linear equation arises from translates of the kernel of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I still don't understand why it is so that the solution is particular solution + general solution of homo. Is it some fundamental nature of diff equations that we stumbled upon?

Comment: Also what I am asking is that why is it that we get a particular solution and not a general solution when we solve?

Comment: It is not the fundamental nature of differential equations, but rather the fundamental nature of **linear** equations, whether differential or not. The idea doesn't work for nonlinear differential equations. The answer to your second question depends on what you mean by "when we solve." There are a variety of methods for finding *one* solution to an inhomogeneous equation, but as my answer shows, there are really infinitely many answers: once you find *one* particular solution, you get others by adding a homogeneous solution.

Comment: By analogy, think about how you would solve the equation $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @symplectomorphic What if we add the arbitrary constant when doing integrations using differential operators for finding particular solution. Wouldn't we get a general solution then?

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing here is a fundamental principle valid in the "linear world". You are given an equation or system of equations
$$Ax=b\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $A$ operates linearly on the input vector $x$, and $b$ is a given constant vector. Such an equation may have no solutions. If it has solutions then they are of the form 
$$x=y_{\rm hom} +x_p\ ,$$
whereby $x_p$ is a *particular solution* of the original equation $(1)$ (maybe found by guessing), and $y_{\rm hom}$ is the *general solution* of the associated homogeneous equation
$$Ay=0\ .\tag{2}$$
Note that the set of solutions of $(2)$ is a *vector space*, which means that any linear combination of "special solutions" of $(2)$ found by "special methods" is again a solution of $(2)$. One last thing: If the RHS of $(1)$ is the sum of two "simpler" vectors: $b=b_1+b_2$, and we can find "particular solutions" $x_p^{(1)}$, $x_p^{(2)}$ of $(1)$ for these "simpler" RHSs then $x_p=x_p^{(1)}+x_p^{(2)}$ is a solution of $(1)$ for the given $b$.

What I have described here applies to  inhomogeneous linear systems of ordinary equations, to inhomogeneous linear systems of ODEs, and to inhomogeneous linear PDEs with homogeneous and inhomogeneous boundary conditions. It is a truly *fundamental principle*: The set of all solutions of $(1)$ is an *affine space*, i.e., a linear space of functions $V$, albeit translated away from the origin by some (not uniquely defined) vector $x_p$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this is a fundamental nature of every linear equation that difference of two solution is a solution of homogeneous equation.

Comment: Also what I am asking is that why is it that we get a particular solution and not a general solution when we solve?